# TcpListener/TcpClient stream.Read() use: is it acceptable to always pass a fixed size max buffer to the stream.Read() call?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

Context:
I have Tcp client/server code. the client always knows the size of what is to be received, so I can pass the exact buffer size of what's expected. On the server side, I would like to read whatever any given client sends to the server that my buffer size allows.

Question: On the TcpListener server side, can I use stream.Read() method and call it with a fixed large buffer size (e.g. 1024) even if my client sent messages have a variable size (e.g. 16 to 1024 bytes) as below?

```
int received = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer);
```

It seems to work, but I wonder if it is reliable/guaranteed to always work (e.g. would the TcpClient small sent messages (e.g. 16 bytes) be always read as soon as it is sent or would it cause the TcpListener server to sometimes wait for more data until buffer is full when calling stream.Read() even if these are several messages sent from the client?

Comment: TCP is an unending stream of bytes. There is no concept of messages, any data sent may be combined or split at will. Each read may or may not get a single blob of data, it may be a full buffer or not a full buffer. (see also https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/message-framing.html) The Nagle alogrithm is relevant here as to what gets sent and received in one go. Large buffers are helpful to performance usually, and 1k isn't actually that big.

Comment: Or in other words: it will return immediately after it got data and not wait for more - but this also means that it returns less than a "message" since TCP does not know what a message in your application is. There is no guaranteed 1:1 relationship between send and receive calls in TCP.

Comment: Steffen thanks: I expect to receive split buffers of the same message but I wanted to understand if I could use a fixed size receive buffer. So it seems from your feedback that : yes it is fine to set a max buffer size and still receive immediately each buffer of any size <= to buffer size.

Comment: Depends on whether Nagle's algorithm is turned on or off

Comment: It seems, it is best is to not assume about that level of detail and not making any assumption on messages boundaries inside the stream, that preferrably have to be reconstructed from the protocol knowledge (header is fixed size and tells how much we must receive next). Now I can see Nagle algorithm may still influence performances depending on the application, as we wait in some cases more to receive combined packets, but on the logical point of you; I think  it would still work with that (fixed header size parsing approach ) whether the algorithm is on or off.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question: yes it is possible to do, but won't be as useful as I expected because TCP only knows about continuous streams of data (not messages with boundaries) so in theory:

- A sender can send one buffer and receiver can receive one more or more buffers for that byte stream to transfer
- Reciprocally, a sender can also send multiple buffers and receiver can read them all in one call (suppose receiver is slower).

But for typical command/response TCP custom protocols, a better approach in my case seems to simply dependency inject one fixed header size expectation (given by the protocol) as well as a delegate to use to determine next buffer length to read for the same message (if any extra length is expected), to my generic server base class.

Then given that header fixed size ; it knows what to parse in the header (thanks to the dependency injected delegate header parser) how much to read next to reconstitute message boundaries and then provides a callback (c# event ) for each of reconstructed message, which would simplify the base class user code greatly in my use case.